# Receiving Invalid personIDs in Identify response with MSFT face API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Was wondering if anyone has crossed upon this problem:

- Using MSFT Cognitive Services Face API to persist Person Groups, Persons and Person Faces
- Am sending an image to the Face-Identify API and receiving a candidate list that includes "phantom" personIds that are not persisted by me and are not listed in the person group used for identification.
  When I run List Persons in a Person Group API I don't receive that personID.

Overall everything is working but for some images I get these invalid responses.
Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated the person group and not trained it since the update?  What do you get if you call the Person Group - Get Person Group Training Status API?

Comment: Hi @kwill  - it was exactly that. Apparently some faces were deleted from the person group and it wasn't retrained in between.

Comment: The way the API is designed forces consuming apps to either train just before identification (which is wasteful if no change to person group) or at delta events to the person group (which makes it difficult to scale because the training loop state needs to be centrally controlled - can't make changes when training inflight). Would be nice if there were an option to set the API to 'auto-train', if required to, just before identification and let MSFT manage training state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from Microsoft Cognitive Service Face Team,

And really sorry for the inconvenience cause by our current training strategy. AFAIK, it is still computation/time cost to train a person group, that is why we make it as an asynchronous call and need training again after the person group is modified.

If you have any further problem, please feel free to update.

Comment: Hi Xuan, thanks for the reply. My point was that because its computationally costly there might be a case for an API mode that MSFT makes the decision whether to train or not based on changes in the person group - 'just-in-time training'. Keep up the great work with the service!

Comment: @ShaiBen-Tovim Thanks for your suggestion and clarification. I will note it down and consider this feature in the future.